# SQL Server: merging multiple colums into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey there I have 2 tables with each multiple columns  and i want to merge them in a view with 1 column.

**table1**

```
data1    data2     data 3
lala     blabla    aaa
```

**table2**

```
data1    data2     data 3
qqq      wwww      eee
```

into 1 view with 1 column

**merged view**

```
data1
lala  
blabla
aaa 
qqqq
wwww 
eee
```

I'm using SQL Server, anyone has an idea :)

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s Oki thx :) well i just wrote it in html so if i click the button it will show the code :)

Comment: yeah, the Stackoverflow site(s) uses something of a "stripped down" version - called "markdown" (instead of markup :-) ) - it's a bit unusual at first, but when you get the hang of it, it's acutally quite powerful and very easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select data1 from table1
union all
select data2 from table1
union all
...
select data3 from table2
```

Comment: Yup. Bear in mind that if you want to see duplicates (if there's a "foo" in table1.data1 and also a "foo" in table1.data2, for example) rather than coalesce them down, use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: @Matt Gibson - yes, had just tried that one and hence edited my answer to make it union all. Thanks.

Comment: This will take 3 passes through each table whereas `unpivot` will just need 1 through each.

Comment: @Rasmus - If you want to apply overall distinct, then use UNION instead of UNION ALL as Matt has suggested in comment.

Comment: @Martin It's a balance, though. I tend to prefer more cross-platform solutions unless performance is actually a problem -- UNION will work in pretty much any SQL engine on the planet, and be more readily understood by more developers. UNPIVOT will work in fewer engines. I'm also not convinced it'll be significantly faster, but I'd have to benchmark it to be sure...

Comment: @Matt - It ought to work anything up to 3 times faster as it is 1 table scan vs 3 table scans. Not sure that tripling the amount of work your queries do for some YAGNI cross platform benefit is particularly wise.

Comment: @Martin Hey, I just said I didn't know and that if it were me, I'd benchmark it before I used it. I'm extremely prepared to be wrong :) As for YAGNI, I guess that depends on where you work and what you do. If each table only had 50 rows, say, I'd go for the UNION every time, but that's because I tend to work with developers who are a lot more likely to have seen UNION than UNPIVOT. If each table had a million rows, that's a different matter...

Comment: @Sachin first of all thx ! it works wonders :) Another thing i was thinking about is how can i create a column besides the one with all the data, telling where it came from. like a string being posted in coloumn2 foreach post. It could be telling that it was a name or phonenumber. Sry if its a bit messy question, tell if you need a better explanation. I just want a static string added foreach post depending on which coloumn they come from. :)

Comment: @Rasmus - You can amend my answer slightly to do that. Just use `SELECT DISTINCT d, data FROM cte` instead of `SELECT data FROM cte`

Comment: @Rasmus - Check martin's comment as given. Else if you want it in my query, you will have to do it like `select data1, 'data1' from table1 union all select data2, 'data2' from table1....`. Basically you need to add same columnname as string beside the column data.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte(data1, data2, data3) As
(
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM table2
)
SELECT data
FROM cte
UNPIVOT  (data FOR d IN 
      (data1, data2, data3)
)AS unpvt
```